# How to give fixed day in to date using php?

Tags: php, date

I want to give fixed day($day=28) to the date using php
following is my code

```
   $next_due_bill_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 months", strtotime($join_date)));
```

Comment: `date('Y-m-28',..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `d` with the number `28`

```
$next_due_bill_date = date('Y-m-28', strtotime("+1 months", strtotime($join_date)));
```

Answer (score 3):

Just set the date function to 28 instead of "d".

```
$join_date = "2018-01-01";
Echo date('Y-m-28', strtotime("+1 months", strtotime($join_date)))."\n"; 
//2018-02-28
```

https://3v4l.org/h5WPe

An alternative method would be to append the string after date function.

```
date('Y-m-', strtotime("+1 months", strtotime($join_date)))."28";
```